# Can two visas be applied at the same time?

Tags: visas

I have a valid visa in the Middle East but I prefer not to pursue going there. Now I want to apply for Japan visa.

Will I have a  problem with that?

Comment: Do you mean "Can I **apply for** two visas as the same time"? or "Can two visas be **applicable** *or* **valid** at the same time?" The first is a common mistake made by non native English speakers but I get the feeling you mean the second since if you already have your visa for somewhere in the Middle East then you already **applied for** it and got it, and you haven't yet **applied for** the Japan visa. So you want to know if two visas in your passport for different places that cover the same date range?

Answer (score 5):

If you already have a valid visa for the middle east, and you are in possession of your passport - there is nothing stopping you from applying for a visa to Japan.

As far as I am aware, Japan does not have any specific restrictions from visitors holding middle eastern visas (or against middle eastern nationals).

To apply for most visas you need to send in your passport. In some exceptional cases you can request your passport be returned while your application is being considered but this is rare.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule you can have multiple valid visas in your passport.  I have five valid visas currently in my passport.

There are a few exceptions, where country A will not stamp a passport with country B's visa or entry stamp.  But these tend to be neighboring countries in conflict with each other.